# Reboot/Poweroff dialogue doesn't work at Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04, but when I want to poweroff / restart my computer, I can't seem to do this from the poweroff button anymore, and the "suspend" and "shutdown" menu options just don't work as well. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Using the Terminal can you reboot/halt?

Comment: @emvidi by the terminal everything works good, but when I press the button, nothing happens